# Clever grouping similar items via CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to group items via cs in an automatic and clever way.
Here is the first demo content:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/ppqszxgb

I've created a custom attribute for each div. **Those custom attributes are not pre-defined, they're populated during page creation.**

Upon creation, I read the attribute and use it with a `:before` css selector to set a "title" for each element, as follows:

```
div:before{
  content: attr(att);
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
}
```

However, I don't want to give title for each item. I only want to use the pseudo element for the first item of each group; preferably resulting close to this:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/pxugtput

Is this possible with css-only? Of not, what's the best option?

Comment: Unless there's another layer of nesting, there's no way to do this via CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but it will get the job done. I set all of the elements into unordered list items according to their groups. And then set the `li:first-child:before` as the content you set.

Here is the code I wrote out: http://cssdeck.com/labs/hhvmvhyg

Don't know if that is the solution you are seeking.